# Using FFT-Convolution when stride>1

Tags: image, image-processing, signal-processing, fft, convolution

The Fourier transform of the convolution (with stride 1) of two images is equivalent to point-wise multiplication of their individual Fourier transforms. I need to perform stride-'n' convolution using the above FFT-based convolution. For some reasons I need to operate in the frequency domain itself after taking the point-wise product of the transforms, and not come back to space domain by taking inverse Fourier transform, so I cannot drop the excess values from the inverse Fourier transform output to get equivalent stride - 'n' convolution. How can I account for the stride in the frequency domain? Thanks.

Comment: I guess `1` is a pixel stride, because the number `1` doesn't make sense otherwise?  I guess your images are monochrome and that you're doing a 1D FFT of the bytes instead of a 2D FFT of the pixel values?  I guess both images are the same size, because otherwise that wouldn't work right?

Comment: Yes, I mean pixel stride. My images are RGB, and I take the 2D FFT of each channel and add these up point-wise. And yes, the second image, i.e. the kernel/weight is also RGB and it is zero-padded to the size of the first image and its FFT is taken in similar way described above - then these two are multiplied point-wise.

Comment: The “strided convolution” used in CNNs are equivalent to a normal convolution followed by downsampling. You can accomplish a similar thing to downsampling by cropping the frequency domain. The exact same result would require adding in the aliasing introduced by downsampling. In short, cropping the frequency domain is *better*.